# Groovy compile fails unreproduceable with stackoverflow

Tags: gradle, groovy

Groovy compilation fails immediatly in gradle build

I have a gradle project using groovy for test cases (Spock framework). Mostly everything works fine but from time to time the code fails (mostly in CI) with a stackoverflow error.

My software version is:

- Gradle 5.6.3
- Java 11 (Open JDK)

I just get the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

This is a sample stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.execute(StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

After changing the build to --full-stacktrace the strace is shown as following:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.execute(StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.WriterController.isInClosure(WriterController.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeCachedCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeCachedCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeCachedCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeCachedCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeCachedCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
...
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.makeCachedCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.indy.InvokeDynamicWriter.prepareIndyCall(InvokeDynamicWriter.java:110)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

This is the core of my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'groovy'
  id 'checkstyle'
  id 'jacoco'
  id 'pmd'
  ...
}

defaultTasks 'bootRun'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  developmentOnly
  runtimeClasspath {
    extendsFrom developmentOnly
  }
}

dependencies {
  compileOnly 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:3.1.12'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

  // language and collection utilities
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

  ....

  //
  // DEVELOPMENT
  //
  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

  //
  // TEST
  //
  testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
  }
  testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
  testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.3-groovy-2.5'

  ....

}

// https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#integrating-with-actuator
springBoot {
  buildInfo {
    properties {
      version = '1' // Removed to get a fixed version of caching
      time = null   // Removed to get a fixed version
    }
  }
}

bootRun {
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', System.getProperty('SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE', 'dev')
}

test {
  shouldRunAfter checkstyleMain, pmdMain, pmdTest, spotbugsMain // fail fast
  maxHeapSize = "2048m"
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', System.getProperty('SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE', 'dev, test')
  testLogging {
    events "SKIPPED", "FAILED"
    exceptionFormat "full"
  }
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  configure(groovyOptions.forkOptions) {
    memoryMaximumSize = '2g'
    jvmArgs = ['-Xmx2g']
  }
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  groovyOptions.fork = false
  groovyOptions.optimizationOptions.put('indy', true)
}
```

Comment: Show stacktrace, show corresponding code where error occurs, then maybe someone will help you...

Comment: Would be great if there **was** a stacktrace. But also the groovy compiler (!) seems to have some internal problem there is no stacktrace.
Maybe someone can give me a link how to debug the groovy compiler (or if there are multiple compiler if I can switch the version).

Comment: Can you try with `--stacktrace`?

Comment: Also, is your build.gradle file small enough to post here

Comment: The build.gradle is pretty large, but I can try extracting the groovy compile part.
Regarding the size, my project has more than 1000 groovy classes, are there any known problems for groovy if the codebase gets pretty large?

Comment: @tim_yates If have added a typical stacktrace.

Comment: If this works on your machine but fails intermittently else where you need to look for environment issues. Are the gradle versions same? Did you try with disable daemon/caching feature?  What is the OS?

Comment: @terribleherbst, do you have any stacktrace items after `Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError` ?

Comment: @daggett No the stacktrace ends with the java.lang.StackoverflowError. There is no message after that.

Comment: @Jayan Gradle is used with the gradle wrapper (so version is the fix). If fails on Mac, Linux and within a docker container. Without changing the code base (same git commit) and without changing the gradle version. On linux the gradle daemon is disabled, on Mac it is enabled (by default).
Is there any cache the groovy compiler is using and which might be related?

Comment: try to use `--full-stacktrace` instead of  `--stacktrace`.maybe there will be more info. then try to add `--debug` and check the log just before exception.

Comment: @daggett is added a full stacktrace maybe this helps.